# How to include a port in PHP FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I want to FTP a certain file from my new server.

The new server does not use the default port `21` but uses `8821`  and I have some problems with my FTP. So I thought this could maybe be the problem.

How to include a port in my current script, or isn't it even needed?

```
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
$currentlog = "$logfile";
$ftp_usernameb = 'username';
$ftp_userpassb = 'pass';
$ftp_serverb = "host";
$ftp_connb = ftp_connect($ftp_serverb) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_serverb");
$loginb = ftp_login($ftp_connb, $ftp_usernameb, $ftp_userpassb);
$local_fileb = "$currentlog";
$server_fileb = "/188.40.46.30:7800/".$currentlog."";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_connb, $local_fileb, $server_fileb, FTP_ASCII))
{
//Downloaded continue with script
?>
<font color="green"><b>The logs have been updated succesfully!</b></font>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?action=done&logfile=<?php echo $_GET['logfile']; ?>&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" />
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<font color="red"><b>Couldn't update logs, contact Jesse!</b></font>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?action=failed&logfile=<?php echo $_GET['logfile']; ?>&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" />
<?php
exit;
}
// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_connb);
```

Thanks alot, I searched alot on the internet but no way how to include it in a PHP script.

Comment: Come on guys! Post a answer :3

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the manual page for [ftp_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php):

```
resource ftp_connect ( string $host [, int $port = 21 [, int $timeout = 90 ]] )
```

Now all you have to do is add the second parameter in your code by changing

```
$ftp_connb = ftp_connect($ftp_serverb) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_serverb");
```

to

```
$port_number = 8821;
$ftp_connb   = ftp_connect($ftp_serverb, $port_number) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_serverb");
```